# Rails - Testing JSON API with functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have just a simple question, but I could not found any answer.

My ruby on rails 3.2.2 appilcation have a JSON API with a devise session authentication.

My question is: **How can I test this API with functional or integration tests - and is there a way to handle a session?**

I do not have a front end, just a API that I can do GET. POST. PUT. and DELETE with JSON Body.

Which is the best way to test this automated?

**EXAMPLE create new user**

POST www.exmaple.com/users

```
{
 "user":{
    "email" : "test@example.com",
    "password " : "mypass"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is easy to do with functional tests. In a user example I would put them in `spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb` in Rspec:

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe UsersController do
   render_views # if you have RABL views

   before do
     @user_attributes = { email: "test@example.com", password: "mypass" }
   end

   describe "POST to create" do

     it "should change the number of users" do
        lambda do
          post :create, user: @user_attributes
        end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
     end

     it "should be successful" do
       post :create, user: @user_attributes
       response.should be_success
     end

     it "should set @user" do
       post :create, user: @user_attributes
       assigns(:user).email.should == @user_attributes[:email]
     end

     it "should return created user in json" do # depend on what you return in action
       post :create, user: @user_attributes
       body = JSON.parse(response.body)
       body["email"].should == @user_attributes[:email]
      end
  end
```

Obviously, you can optimize specs above, but this should get you started. Cheers.

Comment: Why you recommended me to use rspec? What is rspec and what is the difference rspec and normal tests.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal tests"? I just like Rspec for convenient DSL and the verity of helper methods. What are you currently using?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Anthony Eden's talk ["Build and Test APIs with Ruby and Cucumber"](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2141-arrrrcamp2011-build-and-test-apis-with-ruby-and-cucumber)

Answer (score 1):

You can user Cucumber(BDD) to test such cases, for example:

```
Feature: Successful login
  In order to login
  As a user 
  I want to use my super API

  Scenario: List user
    Given the system knows about the following user:
      | email            | username |
      | test@example.com | blabla   |
    When the user requests POST /users
    Then the response should be JSON:
    """
    [
      {"email": "test@example.com", "username": "blabla"}
    ]
    """
```

then, you just need to write your steps, where [pickle](https://www.google.kg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle&ei=_jS9T7_jMsHqOYuavCk&usg=AFQjCNEIVrgJYG7P4BCrPxMpiqFLg4t9zQ) gem 'd be very useful