# rspec integration / request specs vs controller specs with an emphasis on JSON api

Tags: rspec

I have adopted an app that has some test coverage but most of the tests are of mixed quality. The majority of the app is working against a JSON api. I was going to write request specs but authenticating and then sending POST's with the authentication data wasn't trivial. For testing a JSON api, would controller specs be more appropriate?

For example,

```
 match 'api/login-mobile' => 'api#login_mobile', :as => :login_mobile, :defaults => {:format => 'json' }
```

This would seem to be trivial to get at but would require an integration spec with capybara. In addition, capybara wouldn't send session data natively and would require

```
page.driver.post .....
```

I get integration tests for testing UI interactions but it seems like a really bad model for testing a JSON api. Am I missing something? Or is there a tutorial for doing integration / requeset tests? I am looking at discourse right now and pretty much all their tests are controllers .... if integration / request specs were the bees knees, why would they make that decision?

thx in advance

Comment: [Don't use Capybara to test API](https://www.varvet.com/blog/capybara-and-testing-apis/).

Comment: Re: your first question, "for testing a JSON api would controller specs be more appropriate?" It depends on what you are testing? Are you unit-testing controller functionality (returned HTTP status, redirects, model.count changes), JSON content, or cross-purpose things like authentication/authorization?

Answer (score -1):

I would do integration-style tests, somewhat like [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721225/rails-testing-json-api-with-functional-tests).

Interacting with an API endpoint via JSON is higher-level than just the controller, so I would probably  use the `feature` and `scenario` block descriptors provided by RSpec. (example [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara)).

Functionally, it's not much different than a controller spec, but helps push you toward scenario/feature-type of testing, not unit-level testing.